# react native file system, fs, cannot find taken pictures

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-fs, react-native-vision-camera

In my ReactNative application I am using  `"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.13.5"` for taking pictures.

After the picture is taken and uploaded, I want to delete it from the device, but the RNFS (react-native-fs) cannot find the file by the given path on iOS and Android devicess:

I get the error

> iOS ;   [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1BB2256A-ED83-407D-9C76-07431268779B/tmp/ReactNative/CE2FA429-76C8-4BD9-925A-BED09B0B77BB.jpeg']
> Android ;  [Error: File does not exist]

> The path in Android is like: /data/user/0/packagename/cache/mrousavy2423256141715663083.jpg

```js
const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto(); // camera: React.RefObject<Camera> 
const task = storage().ref(<ref>).putFile(photo.path) 
const result = await task.then(); // Firebase Storage can read and upload the photo


RNFS.stat(photo.path)  // <-- Error: The file “CE2FA429-76C8-4BD9-925A-BED09B0B77BB.jpeg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

RNFS.unlink(photo.path) // <-- [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1BB2256A-ED83-407D-9C76-07431268779B/tmp/ReactNative/CE2FA429-76C8-4BD9-925A-BED09B0B77BB.jpeg']

// Prepending file://  Does not work too
RNFS.unlink(`file://${photo.path}`)
RNFS.stat(`file://${photo.path}`)
```

Is it because of access permission that react-native-fs needs?

How does the firebase storage have access to the photo?

Is the path a real temp folder that gets cleared after the app is closed?

why react-native-vision-camera saves media there by default?

Do I really need to remove that media manually or does it get removed?

```
env:
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.13.5",
    physical device : iPhone 8 Plus with iOS 15.5
```

Comment: Could you try adding file:// at the beginning of the path?

Comment: @PrernaBudhraja Did try with `file://`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delete the file as the photos are being stored in a temporary directory. It will be deleted when the app closes.

https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/api/interfaces/PhotoFile

Comment: It does not look like that, at least in Android.
I cleared the cache, took some photos, and the cache reached ~10MB. Closing/killing the app did not reduce the cache size.

Comment: Weird, in that case did you set the read and write files permission in the android manifest?

Comment: I just tried deleting the image on my side and it works, can you add an console.log(await RNFS.stat(photo.path)); and see if it logs anything?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling RNFS.unlink(photo.path) try RNFS.unlink(photo.uri). The react-native-vision-camera API outputs a File object with a URI not a path.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Taking a picture returns a `PhotoFile` object. And if you check the Documentation for [API / Interface: PhotoFile](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/api/interfaces/PhotoFile) There is NO `uri` attribute, but only `path` is defined.